# Why is req.somevariable and res.locals not working with jwt callbacks?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ecmascript-6, express-jwt

We have a `route` & a `middleware` like this:

When we do them like this:

```
//middleware
router.use((req, res, next) => {

    // check header or url parameters or post parameters for token
    let token = req.body.token || req.query.token || req.headers['x-access-token'],


        // verifies secret and checks exp
        jwt.verify(token, config.secret, (err, decoded) => {
            if (err) {
                return res.json({
                    success: false,
                    message: 'Failed to authenticate token.'
                });
            } else {
                // if everything is good, save to request for use in other routes
                res.locals.test = "test";
                req.somevariable = "variable1";

                console.log("res.locals.test inside middleware ", JSON.stringify(res.locals.test));
                console.log("req.somevariable inside middleware ", JSON.stringify(req.somevariable));

                next();

            }
        });

    next();
});

//TestRoute
router.get('/TestRoute', (req, res) => {

    console.log("res.locals.test outside middleware ", JSON.stringify(res.locals.test));
    console.log("req.somevariable outside middleware ", JSON.stringify(req.somevariable));

});
```

The values of `req.somevariable` and `res.locals.test` are `undefined` outside `middleware`

When we do them like this:

```
//middleware
router.use((req, res, next) => {

    res.locals.test = "test";
    req.somevariable = "variable1";

    console.log("res.locals.test inside middleware ", JSON.stringify(res.locals.test));
    console.log("req.somevariable inside middleware ", JSON.stringify(req.somevariable));

    next();

});

//TestRoute
router.get('/TestRoute', (req, res) => {

    console.log("res.locals.test outside middleware ", JSON.stringify(res.locals.test));
    console.log("req.somevariable outside middleware ", JSON.stringify(req.somevariable));


});
```

The values of `req.somevariable` and `res.locals.test` are available outside `middleware`.

What is the problem here?

Comment: You calling next() twice in first middleware example - it may cause unexpected results

Comment: @Nosyara Oh, this was the catch. I removed it and got it working. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

`res.locals.VARIABLENAME = req.user`

`VARIABLENAME` (whatever variable you set it to) can show up as undefined when you use `.ejs` or when dynamic rendering with that variable, you can get errors like your variable name is undefined.

THIS IS AN ODDITY with `res.locals`: when you want to use the variable name you set to `res.locals` with rendering, you have to define `req.user` in your function THAT RENDERS THE FILE!

Backend: `res.locals.currentUser = req.user`

```
//THIS FUNCTION WILL RENDER PERFECTLY LETTING ME USE currentUser in my .ejs file
 upgradeForm(req, res, next) {
    let saved = req.user;
    if(req.user){
      res.render("users/upgrade");
    } else{
      req.flash("notice", "You've successfully signed in!");
      res.redirect("/");
    }
  }
```

HOWEVER

```
//THIS FUNCTION WILL SAY currentUser is UNDEFINED IN MY .ejs file
 upgradeForm(req, res, next) {
    if(req.user){
      res.render("users/upgrade");
    } else{
      req.flash("notice", "You've successfully signed in!");
      res.redirect("/");
    }
  }
```

No code difference except for that the working function rendering has `req.user` set to a variable (you don't even have to use that variable). Took me 9 hours to solve this problem but now you know!